# What are the requirements for a good Cast in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, casting

I have a list with the following data...

```
Device [id=1, deviceType=Camera ,groupId=-1, state=0],
Device [id=2, deviceType=Camera ,groupId=-1, state=0],
Device [id=14, deviceType=Camera ,groupId=-1, state=0],
```

I'm trying to cast it with `as` but get null.

```
var c:CameraAsn= (value[0] as CameraAsn);
```

if I use a normal cast I get coercion errors. So I'm assuming the casting does not like what I'm trying to do. What I'm try to learn here is what are the rules for a cast? My `CameraAsn` extends from a device class that has all of these properties accessible in the way of get/set's.

example:

```
protected var _groupId:Number = -1;

public function get groupId():Number
{
    return _groupId;
}

public function set groupId(value:Number):void
{
    _groupId = value;
}
```

Is that not going to work?

Comment: From the above it looks like you didn't initialize new instances of Device anywhere - so of course you can't cast nothing to anything. ;)

Comment: **(1)** Is your _"list"_ in a `String` or what? **(2)** What is the result of `trace( "value is : " + value[0] );`? Are you expecting one of those `1, 2, 14` numbers? **(3)** Also wouldn't it just be easier to setup your `CameraAsn` class to expect a number as input parameter like `var c :CameraAsn = new CameraAsn(14);`?